# Set State with Props from Parent Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, state

Is there a way to set the `state` in a `Component` with the `Props` the `Component` receives from a `Parent Component?`

```
export default class SomeComp extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = someProps; // <-- I need the props to be the state of the Component
    }


    render() {
        const { someProps } = this.props;
        ...
    }
}
```

Or can I write a function, something like

```
export default class SomeComp extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

    }

    _setProps = (someProps) => {
          this.State = someProps;
    }

    render() {
        const { someProps } = this.props;
        this._setProps(someProps);
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: first it's not a good practice of storing all the props values in state of child component, use this to solve your problem: `this.state = props`

Comment: @MayankShukla I think I need more code to understand what you mean. I need to pass props from parent component to child component because a function in the child component needs to process the props from parent component in order to render itself (a list, ...). But, for more behaviour, I need the props from parend component to be written into the state of the child component

Comment: inside constructor of child `this.state = {keyName: props.keyName}` now data in keyName from parent will get stored in state of child component.

Comment: @MayankShukla I write the props in parent component with `this.state = ....` in the `constructor`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Mayank Shukla mentioned, it is bad practice to store parent props in a childs state, thus managing the state within the child.

The whole idea of passing down the props to the child is, that you needn't care about state within the child, because it's all trickling down from the parent.

Child components should only care about their state.

What you should do instead (and what is good react practice) is to have the state in the parent component and pass event handlers down to the child which will change the state on the parent.

```
// in parent
class MyParentComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      data: someData;
    };
  }

  handleChange(data) {
    this.setState(data);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <MyChildComponent
        data={this.state.data}
        handleChange={this.handleChange}
      />
    );
  }
}



class MyChildComponent extends React.Component {
  // this is going to update the data in parent
  // and trickle it back down to the child
  this.props.handleChange({ foo: 'bar' });
}
```

Comment: this is true on paper but as code grows bigger there are a few use cases that contradict this statement.. for example deep stack of components or `screen` components that do should not hold state logic for all children and their children components etc etc.. even though they do sometimes need to set some logic on them

Comment: well at that point you probably want to look at something like redux anyways.
that is what they mean when they say "don't use redux until you need to use redux".

Comment: usually at the point you understand you "need/must" to use central state management its already way way to late and the refactoring going to be horrible.. for me.. if its something that will go to production - its central state from the get go.. learned it the hard and bloody way

Answer (score 0):

The recommendation is to keep the kids states in the parent component. So the `parent.state` will eventually contain  `children` section, where the kids states can be stored under unique ids.

```
this.state = {
     title: 'Some title',
     // other local stateful attributes
     children:{
        kidId1:{
          kidAttr1:' 'value'
        },
        ....
        kidId100:{
          kidAttr1:' 'value'
        }
     }
};
```

Comment: how would I access the props from parent in child component?

Comment: Parent should get the kid state and pass it to kid constructor.